# Why doesnt the title show up in this templates generated pdf?

Tags: templates

https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cover-letters/moderncv-classic/

I m changing the line

```
\title{Resumé title}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
```

to

```
\title{Cover Letter}
```

But this title doesnt show up in the pdf.
WHy?

Comment: Because `\title` is defined but not used in `moderncv.cls`.

Comment: how to solve this issue?

Comment: If you want to use the `\title` you have to substitute `\makelettertitle` with `\makecvtitle` in your document.